# Is the .net framework being phased out in the future

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version

Is the .net framework being phased out in the future or going to be completely replaced with the .net core?

As a developer we need to know if we should put more focus on .net core or will we still have the 2 options going into the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily opinion-based and asking to divine the future.

Comment: Recollecting from memory of dotnetrocks podcasts, .Net framework is not going away anytime soon + there's no plans on getting rid of Framework at all at this point.
But as mentioned, this is probably not the correct place to ask this question.

Comment: @KevinAnderson,I am not asking anyone to define the future, I am just asking if anyone has heard of Microsoft shutting down .net framework in the near future to focus and move everyone to the .net core. I'm not asking for opinions on the question but looking for facts. I think this question is related to programmers in the .net platform because this could make a difference to a persons career when learning a skill or working on future projects.

Comment: @sniels, thanks, I was hoping that Microsoft would keep both running. I just wanted to make 100% sure before working on new projects.

Comment: This site isn't a general "ask anything about any computing topic" site.  That's why it's off-topic.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home is probably what you want.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, Thanks, I will take note of that.

Comment: @C.duPreez On the DotNetRocks podcast that was released today, you can hear Scot Hunter say that .NET Framework will never go away. It's a fundamental part of Windows.
https://www.dotnetrocks.com/?show=1543